# Wordpress New User Registration Email Is not Sent?

Tags: wordpress, registration

I want to add new users on my wordpress site so that they can guest blog on my site. I have enabled new user reg from my wordpress settings. When new user fill up the reg form then I get an email that new user added but the user do not receive any email with password? What can I do? Please help anyone.

Regards,
Abdul

Comment: Have you checked the spam folder? I just enabled it on my site and it sent the registration email to my spam folder.

Comment: Yes, but there was no mail. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried sending it to another email address? Or installing wp again (as say wptest) and see if the email will send then?

Comment: check your site email configuration and try send test email using php mail and clarify email function is work..,i think this is problem with your mail configuration.